# What is the unit of measurement returned of the function QPainterPath::length() const

Tags: python, pyqt5

I used qpainterpath length function on my python code to determine the length of the path of two points. I obtain a value, but I am not sure what unit of measurement this function returns. Does anyone here have an idea?

Comment: The "unit" is that of any [cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system): if you have a graph with a line from (0, 0) to (10, 0), the length is 10. They may be pixels, millimeters, inches, and that depends on what actually "draws" that path (on the screen, on an image, when printed on paper, etc).

Comment: I draw the path on top of an image, so does that mean which makes it unit into pixels?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "draw on top of an image": is the painter created on the image? Or is the image drawn with `drawPixmap` or `drawImage`? Or is it shown on an underlying object? It always depends on the device the painter is set (and its eventual transformations).

Comment: I am using drawPixmap

Comment: Then those are units based on the *surface* used for the QPainter. Note that if the draw function *scales* the image (as explained in the [`drawPixmap()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPixmap) documentation, if the first argument is a QRect that has a size that doesn't *agree* with the pixmap size), the "units" won't be properly *aligned* to the pixmap. Please do some proper studying on the cartesian coordinate system and also the [Qt one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html). "Units" are relative values, not absolute: "1" could be a pixel, a millimeter or even a light year.

Comment: Thank you. How about if I will used drawImage instead of drawPixmap. Will it change something? I just want to get the length of line in pixel based on the line that I draw on the Image.

Comment: That depends on how you're using the function, as explained above, and if you applied other transformations. And only you can know that, so I strongly suggest you to carefully read the links above and patiently study the documentation.